# opencart 3 ,How to edit required Fields to not required from admin edit order?

Tags: field, opencart, required

I need to  edit required Fields to not required, like lastname ,county ..
in admin/ sale/ edit order
and Edit Customer / Edit Customer ?

I have edit  admin/view/template/sale/order_form.tpl
and delete required

But It still not working

Does somebody know how to do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the order in admin, you send a request to catalog/controller/api/customer to save the information about the customer. In this file that is validated the data.

See a part of the code who validates the fields inside catalog/controller/api/customer:

```
if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) > 32)) {
    $json['error']['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
}

if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) > 32)) {
    $json['error']['lastname'] = $this->language->get('error_lastname');
}

if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || (!filter_var($this->request->post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
    $json['error']['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
}

if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 32)) {
    $json['error']['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
}
```

If you want to turn the lastname field as not required, only remove its validation.

This is only for customer infos inside Sale edit.